# Unhide everything in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word

I used the search function in Word 2016 to hide everything that is not highlighted. As a result I get only highlighted text showing. However when I want to unhide it, only certain part of the text shows, for example: my Word document consists of section breaks, whenever I try to unhide everything, footers and headers remain hidden. I have to go through each header and footer and unhide them manually.

Is there a way to force it using the replace function to unhide everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't gotten a response yet, so perhaps you'd be interested in working with a macro that works in Word 2010? This macro unhides all hidden text, including text in the headers and footers.

```
Sub UnhideEverything()

Dim rngStory As Range
Dim rngToSearch As Range
Dim rngResult As Range
For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
               Set rngToSearch = rngStory
    Set rngResult = rngToSearch.Duplicate

    Do
        If rngResult.Font.Hidden Then
            rngResult.Font.Hidden = False

        End If
        rngResult.MoveStart wdWord
        rngResult.End = rngToSearch.End
    Loop Until rngResult.Find.Found = False

    Next rngStory

End Sub
```